# i want to copy a string from cellA to cellB in a "for" loop

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to copy cells in specific locations to other cells, keep telling me the following:

> Run-time error '1004':
>
> Method '_Default' of object 'Range' failed

Code:

```
Sub test()
Dim rng As Range, i As Integer, j As Integer, a As Integer, b As Integer, totalvalue As Double
Dim rname(10) As Integer, cname(10) As Integer, namelocation() As Integer
Dim name As String, Row As Integer, Column As Integer

a = 2
b = 1
c = 1
d = 2

totalvalue 0

    Set rng = Range("A28:Z28")

    For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
        For j = 1 To rng.Columns.Count
        totalvalue = totalvalue + rng(i, j)

        If rng(i, j) > 100 Then
            Cells(2, a) = rng(i, j)
            a = a + 2
            rname(b) = i
            cname(b) = j
            b = b + 1
        End If
        Next
    Next

Cells(4, 2) = totalvalue

Dim element As Variant
Dim element1 As Variant

r = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(rname)

For k = 1 To r

    Row = rname(k) — 17
    Column = cname(k) — 4

    'error occurs here
    name = Cells(Column, Row).String

    Cells(c, d).Value = name
```

**imported from original image**

Here's how it looks in my editor:

[image]

Comment: Please consider typing the code into the question rather than pasting an image. This makes it easier to read and search.

Comment: `name = Cells(column, row).String` you probably mean `name = Cells(column, row).Text`... Range has no such `.String` method.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `.Value` or `.Text` instead of `.String`